# Next.js - When use dynamic/import, so router.push (shallow:true) not working. Always refresh

Tags: dynamic, next.js, router

I'm using Next 12.1

And i'm using dynamic import for import Components. And i want to use feautre router.push with shallow:true.

But when i call router.push (with shallow:true) so component re-render (flickr, refresh) always. When i import component directly, so component not re-render.

Any help please.

```
import Jaak from "@components/cloud/Project/Cozy/jaak"; //direct import
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
```

Use Component

```
const RenderComponent = dynamic(
() =>
import("@components/cloud/Project/Cozy/jaak")
);

return <RenderComponent />; //with refresh
return <Jaak />; //no refresh
```

Can i use dynamic import and use router.push with shallow.true? (i want no refresh the component)

This is the sample
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-ccx2zk?file=components%2FJaakDynamic.js

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. Calling `router.push` will always re-render the component, no matter if it's dynamically imported or not.

Comment: I solver this problem. Solution: Wrap useMemo to dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

Solution: Wrap useMemo to dynamic.

[image]